# Simple glmnet model, predict() results in 'Error in lambda[1] - s : non-numeric argument to binary operator'

Tags: r, glmnet, r-parsnip

So I've been trying to use `predict()` with various forms of dataframe formats, but they don't seem to work. I've tried 1) excluding the dependent variable, 2) including the dependent variable with sliced data, 3) including dependent variable with NA values in it, and many other things.

```
R 4.1.0
R Studio 1.4.1717
```

The code below demonstrates 3).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(tidymodels)

df <- data.frame(y  = sample(5000000:120000000, 100, replace = TRUE),
                 yearr = sample(2015:2021, 100, replace = TRUE),
                 monthh = sample(1:12, 100, replace = TRUE),
                 dayy = sample(1:31, 100, replace = TRUE))

rm(df_slice)
df_slice = df |>
  slice(1:50) |>
  select(yearr, monthh, dayy) |>
  mutate(y = NA)

m = linear_reg(mode = 'regression', penalty = varying(), mixture = 0.6) |>
  set_engine("glmnet") |>
  fit(y ~ ., data = df)

predict(m, df_slice)
predict.model_fit(m, df_slice)
predict_raw(m, df_slice)
```

The last three lines of code throw `Error in lambda[1] - s : non-numeric argument to binary operator` debug messages. I made sure that all of the variables are numeric in both `df` and `df_slice` but still unsure of what is going on. I just want to get the predicted/fitted values, as well as 'future' values if I were to do a train-test split. Why is this not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a `glmnet`, and the `penalty` you are tuning is the L2 norm which is also known as `lambda` in glmnet, see [the help page](https://glmnet.stanford.edu/articles/glmnet.html)

If you set `penalty = varying()` , you are running glmnet across a series of L2 norm, and when you call predict, you need to provide a value of lambda to predict. So with your example now, you should not use `penalty = varying()` but provide a value of `lambda` :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(tidymodels)

m = linear_reg(mode = 'regression', penalty = 1, mixture = 0.6) %>%
  set_engine("glmnet") %>%
  fit(y ~ ., data = df)

predict(m, df_slice)
```

Otherwise, you need to tune and find a suitable `lambda`, then pass this to refit the model:

```
my_cv = vfold_cv(df)
rec = recipe(y ~. ,data=df) %>% prep(training = df,retain=TRUE)
fit = linear_reg(mode = 'regression', penalty = tune(), mixture = 0.6) %>%
  set_engine("glmnet") 

wflow = workflow() %>%
add_recipe(rec) %>%
add_model(fit)

res = wflow %>% tune_grid(my_cv)

best_params = res %>% select_best(metric = "rmse")

m = wflow %>%
  finalize_workflow(best_params) %>%
  fit(data = df)

predict(m,df_slice)
```